# Meaning of 'Section Work'?

Tags: terminology

> Arturo O’Farrill’s Afro Latin Jazz Orchestra is one of the best jazz
>   orchestras in existence, a powerhouse outfit whose precise section
>   work is enhanced by thrilling soloists.

Please define 'section work' in this context.

Answer (score 6):

They are talking about sections in the sense of a group of related instruments, such as a [horn section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_section#Popular-music_horn_section).

*Precise section work* refers to their capability of playing together in a tight and groovy way. This section work is contrasted to the soloists, who would usually play (often improvised) melodies backed by one or more sections accompanying them.

Answer (score 3):

When a large group splits into smaller *sections*, there will be maybe 4,5,6 players in that section. It could be a sax section, a rhythm section,, etc., who work well together and play 'in the pocket'. Arrangements may involve a soloist, or several soloists, in a longer piece, playing solos being backed by a *section*.